# What is the easiest and cheapest way to store big money with option to any moment get then in cash?

Tags: finance, banking, investment, money, transportation

Imagine I have a lot of money and my number 1 aim is to store them somewhere where I can get them fast if I need them.
I don’t want to have dividends from my money but if I will it  would be great.

For example banks are asking to wait some time before I can get big number of money in cash or even to transfer them. So banks don’t look like a good fit for my goals.

Advice me something please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this really isn't a personal finance advice website

Comment: @EnergyNumbers It’s your right. Appreciate your vote.

Comment: This should be moved to personal finance.  You also need to state what country you are in.  The country and sometimes the territory would completely change the answer.